# "Loading operating system... boot error" when booting from live CD

Tags: installation, boot-failure, live-cd, iso

I'm having a problem installing Ubuntu 12.10 on a new drive.  I was running Windows7 on my SSD but when the drive crashed, I decided to use that as an excuse to make the switch to Ubuntu.  I've been experimenting with it on my old laptop until I got my SSD replaced under warranty.

Now I have my SSD back and want to install Ubuntu on my desktop machine.  I used UNetbootin to make a bootable flash drive.  I then I went into my BIOS and made sure USB loaded before the hard drive.  However, when I try to load it I get an error that says:

```
Loading operating system ...
boot error
```

I know the flash drive works because if I reboot my laptop or my other Windows PC with the flash drive and it loads into Ubuntu...just when I try to do it in the PC with no OS currently on the drive.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the bootable flash drive made from the Startup Disk Creater. then try booting the PC with the flash drive.

Answer (score -1):

UNetbootin didn't work for me either. It's better [to use Startup Disk Creator](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows). So find some friend with Ubuntu OS laptop, make a startup disk and boot. That's what i did.

Comment: Startup Disk Creator is a Windows program, not an Ubuntu program. You don't need Ubuntu to run it. (I edited your answer to link to information on using Startup Disk Creator but I didn't want to change the intended meaning of your post. Still, I recommend editing your answer, since Startup Disk Creator runs on Windows and actually *does not run on Ubuntu*.)